# How to override XMessages for adding new locale and override existing messages

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am trying to override existing XMessages_xx.properties files. I was able to add a new locale by adding a new XMessages_xx.properties file under com/sencha/gxt/messages/client package in my project (Note: I am not making changes inside GXT jar). But I was not able to override existing messages using the same technique.

Does anyone know the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get around this by placing the XMessages_xx.properties in classpath before the gxt jar.